# According Facebook Platform Policy, Could I save UID in my secure database?

Tags: facebook, policy

According to Facebook Platform policy, Could I save UID in my secure database?

The reason for that is , I want to remember user when they use Facebook account login to my website. For example, they like post and I want to remember them access to some restricted area.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , but you must remove it if the user deauths your app, and you can't share it outside your app. If you need to share it, use the third party id instead.

The auth docs (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/) have details on how to handle deauths.